# Camera works perfectly in flex emulator but not on device

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, android-camera

I have a project that uses video for a chat application, I can get it to work in the flex emulator but when I deploy it to the device the button that initiates the video doesn't change and video never starts.  My devices all have 2 cameras except my computer but specifiying `Camera.getCamera([1])` didn't change anything except mess up my emulator and cause a `NullPointerException`.   `Camera.getCamera([0])` works just the same as not having the ID.  I have tried messing with different values quality and nothing makes a difference.  Any one who can explain enabling debug logs can have them.  Thanks!

```
private function publishVideo():void{
_publishingVideo = true;

_ns = new NetStream(_nc);
_ns.client = this;
_ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStreamStatus);
_cam = Camera.getCamera();
_cam.setQuality(0,0);
_cam.setMode(160, 120, 10);
```

Comment: The emulators don't work very well.  Have you debugged the code on the device to see if you get errors or whatnot?

Answer (score 1):

debug helped, I had another piece that was stopping it before it got to my camera and all is well now thanks for pushing me to figure out debug enable